# Spring Class Controller Doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, maven

I tried to do a simple Spring Project. I use server Tomcat 7.0. When i write http://localhost:8090/springProject/ into my url, it works properly. But when i try to use the class controller (with @RequestMapping("/hello")) it doesn't work. I tried to use a lot of solutions, but nothing works. Any suggestions? Thanks

Class Controller:

```
package it.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView showMessage(
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
    mv.addObject("message", message);
    mv.addObject("name", name);
    return mv;
}
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="2.5">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="it.spring"/>

    <bean

class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

View helloworld.jsp (inside src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views):

```
 <%@ taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix="c"%>
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 4 MVC -HelloWorld</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <h2>${message} ${name}</h2>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Appears: HTTP Status 404 - /springProject/hello

Comment: http://localhost:8090/springProject/hello/please

Comment: post the code plz

Comment: show your controller source

Comment: If you want someone to give you a constructive answer you need to add all relevant code & configuration details to the original question

Comment: @NicolaColella please edit question and add that code there and share your configuration

Comment: Code added in question

Comment: Your controller class seems to be in the default package. But you're scanning `it.spring`. Yu also didn't post your view nor told us how it was named and where it was located. It's also really weird to start a new project with an old tomcat 7, a very old 2.5 webapp version, an old XML spring config instead of Java-based config, and without using spring-boot.

Comment: @JBNizet updated

Comment: What if you try with localhost....8080/hello?

Comment: I set port 8090 because 8080 is already busy, so with 8080 it does'nt work

Comment: Your code works fine, so it must be a configuration issue, how do you run it? You are building a war and then deploy it to tomcat `webapps` directory or run it from IDE or perhaps using some maven plugin?

Comment: Where did you mentioned "/springProject/" in the code? What is the response for http://localhost:8090/hello?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. You can clear the tomcat working directory and then do a clean build and deploy the app to tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable annotation-driven Spring MVC controllers in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using an XML-based configuration so you can go with:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

to enable MVC.

If you are going with annotation-based configuration, use

```
 @EnableWebMvc
```

to enable MVC.